# Example Apps that uses Windows 8 in-app purchase system in the Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

Are there any apps in Windows Store that uses in-app purchase system?

If yes, which ones are that?

Comment: Do you need a sample or do you want to see the way it's implemented in those apps?

Comment: Yes, I want see the way it's implemented on those apps; but No need to sample thanks.

Comment: Here's a sample which may help you [Trial app and in-app purchase sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a) [How to support in-app purchases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordastic and Word Recon are two games I've seen with live In-App purchases.

At present, Wacky Wordsearch seems to have made it to the store with simulated IAPs, if you want to see that process.

Comment: Thanks! Word Recon was a great sample!